# Guitar Pro voicings limitation. Need Guitar Pro expert!

Tags: guitar, guitar-pro

In a nutshell, I'm trying to move a rest, because Guitar Pro (perhaps rightly) sees a minor 3rd and won't allow them to be separate voicings. In the picture below you'll see the quarter rest should be ABOVE the whole note and then the measure would look fine! I've tried toying with all 4 voicings and "multi-voice" mode, but cant seem to find a solution ( I need autonomy, which is one area I'm finding Guitar Pro really falls short!)

As you can see, I'm trying to avoid having to tie the F note throughout the measure which is tie-overkill in my opinion - messy looking and harder to read.  Let me know if you have any recommendations. Of course, one fix is just to make the F a quarter note and leave it up to the player, but I'm transcribing a piece and I hate to sacrifice precision if I don't have to.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do. I can confirm that you can't choose the location of the rest (I agree the automatic position is wrong, it should be above), but anyone who can properly read a sheet music will see what it means. What I see on your screenshot is that the notes are on their own voicings, right ? It's just the rest that is not correctly positioned ? You may try to hide the rest (I think you can do that in the Stylesheet - F7 shortcut)

Comment: Yea, but it still looks unprofessional even if the reader can figure it out. Thanks anyway. I think it's more practical just to make it a quarter note and move along.

Comment: As you wish, but then you change the music ;) (Guitar Pro won't let the note ring, and the reader would probably not understand it either).

Comment: It would be impossible for the f note to last a whole beat. I think it would be a half beat if anything.

Comment: Good observation, that is certainly true. I just made it a quarter for simplicity. Hopefully the player will have the sense of taste to hold it a beat.

Comment: I do not know if I understand correctly, and I think it happens just like other users. Why not post what you want to do, the original score (even if it is handwritten)? In any case sure that in Finale you do not have this problem.

Comment: Still no solution in Guitar Pro 7.5. A workaround would be to export the piece to MusicXML, and import the file in another software and maybe edit the position of the "rest" from there.

Answer (score 2):

Guitar Pro has a `Let ring` feature, which will essentially act as if you have held the note and is common in guitar tab. The limitations of this are the same as the limitations of writing a longer note - it will be interrupted by rests or by other notes being played on the same string, and the note's volume will still eventually decay similar to holding down a note.

To use it, highlight the note/notes you wish to ring out and either find it in the UI (it's in a different place in every iteration of Guitar Pro I've used), find it in the `Tools` menu, or use the keyboard shortcut `i`.